# How do I set a default value for an Aspect property in Alfresco?

Tags: alfresco

How do I set a default value for an Aspect property in Alfresco? Would that be a constraint or is there an attribute on the property itself?

This is my property:

```
    <constraint name="ac:Priority_Options" type="LIST">
        <parameter name="allowedValues">
            <list>
                <value>Low</value>
                <value>Medium</value>
                <value>High</value>
            </list>
        </parameter>
    </constraint>

            <property name="ac:propPriority">
                <title>Priority</title>
                <type>d:text</type>
                <multiple>false</multiple>
                <constraints>
                    <constraint ref="ac:Priority_Options" />
                </constraints>
            </property>
```

Answer (score 2):

As described in [Additional Property Capabilities](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Data_Dictionary_Guide#Additional_Property_Capabilities):

```
        <property name="ac:propPriority">
            <title>Priority</title>
            <type>d:text</type>
            <multiple>false</multiple>
            <default>my default value</default> <!-- !! -->
            <constraints>
                <constraint ref="ac:Priority_Options" />
            </constraints>
        </property>
```